# É possível comparar itens sem if?

Tags: python

Eu me desafiei agora pouco a desenvolver uma função que retorne se um número é maior que 5 sem o uso de nenhum operador de comparação, como *assertion*, *while*, operador ternário, *if* que compare direta ou indiretamente o numero dado com 5.

O retorno poderia ser True/False ou 0/1.

Tentei usar operadores bitwise, mas não tive sucesso e nem uma "clue" com isso.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtrai e compara com 0, mas só daria certo com números. Aí dá até pra emendar um and e ter alguma coisa parecida com um if em alguns casos.

```py
a = 5

a - 5 == 0 and 3
```

Retorna o 3, aí dá pra juntar uns operadores lógicos e fazer mais coisas.

Comment: Isso é basicamente um hack, mas é a mesma coisa, basicamente (*a-5 == 5-5*)

Comment: Então nem entendi o que você quer, tem algum exemplo do que você quer em outra linguagem? O lance é o and depois da expressão, ele pega a primeira se for `True` e avalia o resto, ou só retorna `False`.

Comment: Eu disse ali em cima: "sem o uso de nenhum operador de comparação, como [...] que compare direta ou indiretamente o numero dado com 5."

Comment: Acho que não tem jeito então, você pode até inventar uma outra função com um caractere que compare diretamente números. Tipo nessas linguagens funcionais até dá pra criar uma função que aceita um argumento e compara com um número (com pouco boilerplate), mas dentro dela ainda vai ter um `== ou > ou <=`. Um exemplo em haskell seria montar uma função que aceita um número e retorna um bool, aí chama ela com o número que você quer comparar, a sintaxe ficaria `fn 2` pra comparar o 2 por exemplo, aí a função ficaria `fn x = x > 5`. Mas nem serve pra code golfing.